# Modify from python of kivy dropdown button text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Snippet of `main.kv`

```
<PositionSelection>:
    name: 'PositionSelection'
    # pos_sel_button: sel_button
    id: sel_button_id
    GridLayout:
        rows:2
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        Button:
            id: position_button
            text: 'Position'
```

After created the button (`id: position_button`) in `kv` I will add a list of buttons in `python`, but I need to modify from `python` file the text (defined as `'Position'`) suddenly without any action on it. Has someone any idea?

Comment: read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: from inside the `PositionSelection` class you can do `self.ids.position_button.text='Not Position'` or `self.ids['position_button'].text='Not Position'`. See the [Documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=ids#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids).